# In the local ring of an algebraic plane curve, are all elements expressible as a rational function of a local parameter?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $P$ be a non-singular point on an algebraic plane curve $C$.  Then the local ring $\mathcal{O}_P (C)$ has a unique maximal ideal, and this ideal is principally generated.  Let $t$ be any such generator - this is a "local parameter at $P$".  Is it the case that any $\varphi \in \mathcal{O}_P (C)$ is expressible as $\varphi = f / g$ with $f$, $g$ polynomial in $t$?

Comment: No: it would imply that (eg for $C$ irreducible) $K(C)$ is exactly $K(t)$, which excludes for instance elliptic curves or higher genus closed curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true. Reduce to the case $C$ irreducible. The stated condition happens iff $C$ is rational the statement implies that $\mathcal{O}_{C,P}\cong k[t]_{(t)}$, which is equivalent to $C$ rational. For a concrete example, check the local ring of a point on an elliptic curve.

Comment: Nice.  Here is a concrete example: consider the point $(0,0)$ on the elliptic curve $y^2 = x * (x - 1) * (x + 1)$.  Then $y$ is a local parameter.  If $x = f/g$ where $f, g$ are polynomials in $y$, then by substitution, $y^2 g^3 = f (f + g) (f - g)$.  Considering the degrees in $y$ of both sides one sees that there are no non-negative integers deg(f), deg(g) that could possibly satisfy the constraints.